# Extra string added during input system call in C

Tags: c, linux

When I compile this using GCC on linux, as I am waiting for input, the "hi" shows up. I do not want to use scanf, and want to know why the hi is showing while I am asking the user to input the name. Also when I want to printout the name of the file that was just passed, I get garbage characters. In netbeans, i get what I want. but on linux, it decides to act weirdly. please help

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
char val[70];
        if(write(1, "Please input your name", 36)!=36)
        {
                return -1;
        }
        if(read(0, val, 36) < 0)
        {}

        if(write(1, val, 36)!=36)
        {}

printf("Yo");//THIS IS PRINTING OUT WAY BEFORE IT IS CALLED, ANY VARIABLE WITH A STRING     GETS PRINTED OUT, EVEN WITHOUT PRINTF BEING INVOKED
}
```

output:

```
Please input the file nameYo: hi
hi
???Om?0?a?Sm?  <<WHAT IS THIS? I DONT GET THIS ON NETBEANS
```

Comment: Are you sure that `"Please input your name"` is 36 characters - I'm not very good at counting always, but I get 22 or some such... Of course, "Yo" will probably be stored shortly after this string...

Comment: Your output string is not 36 bytes, so you are lying to to the system, but expect it to do the right thing. That's usually doesn't work.

Comment: Don't mix calls to read/write with calls to C stdio functions like fread/fwrite/printf. Use one or the other, or you will get very confused by the way they buffer input and output.

Comment: How do I know the size of what the user passed without libc? right now I am getting extra garbage like ???Om?0?a?Sm? < since I am using it is 36 bytes but in reality I dont know

Comment: @MichaelDay please read above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument to `write` is the byte length of the string you're trying to print. You have 36, but the string you provide is only 22 bytes long. Changing the code to look like the following will behave as you expected it to:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char val[70];
    if(write(1, "Please input your name", 22)!=22)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if(read(0, val, 36) < 0)
    {}

    if(write(1, val, 36)!=36)
    {}

    printf("Yo");//THIS IS PRINTING OUT WAY BEFORE IT IS CALLED, ANY VARIABLE WITH A STRING     GETS PRINTED OUT, EVEN WITHOUT PRINTF BEING INVOKED
}
```

Note that you should probably look into using `printf` and `scanf` so that you wont have to worry about byte lengths so much.

That might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char val[70];
    printf("Please input your name");

    if(scanf("%69s", &val) == 1)
        printf(val);

    printf("Yo");
}
```

Comment: How would I know the length of what the user just passed me without calling a libc function? For example, if I want to print out what the user just stored, I need to pass the exact bytes otherwise I will get garbage characters.

Comment: if you see, right now in my read I am assuming it is 36 bytes

Comment: @user1888502- Why can't you use anything from libc?  You do realize that `read()` and `write()` are part of libc, right?

Comment: You'll need to use scanf instead of read. This way you wont need to know how many bytes the user is passing. I've updated my comment to include a method using `printf` and `scanf`

Comment: @user1888502 The read() call returns the number of bytes you've read. You should only print out that many bytes.